# How do I dynamically Embed div inside a div

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, fetch-api

I want to loop through the products and show all products inside a div through the data I am getting in my response.
This is my div inside which I want to embed my products div:

```
<div class="row" id="">
                     <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4">
                        <div class="product-item discount">
                            <div class="product-item-inner">
                                <span class="discount">-25%</span>
                                <a href="./products/product-details.html" class="link">
                                    <figure class="img-box">
                                        <img src="../assets/img/products/quantum.png" alt="Ore Quantum PWG927.650">
                                    </figure>
                                </a>
                                <div class="details">
                                    <span class="cat"><i class="uil uil-tag-alt"></i> Quantum</span>
                                    <a href="./products/product-details.html" class="link">
                                        <h5 class="title">Ore Quantum PWG927.650</h5>
                                    </a>
                                    <div class="star">
                                        <i class="fa-solid fa-star"></i>
                                        <i class="fa-solid fa-star"></i>
                                        <i class="fa-solid fa-star"></i>
                                        <i class="fa-solid fa-star"></i>
                                        <i class="fa-solid fa-star-half-stroke"></i>
                                        <h4><span class="old-prc">169.00&euro;</span>135.20&euro;</h4>
                                    </div>
                                    <a href="./single-products.html" class="go-to-cart"><i class="uil uil-shopping-bag shopping-cart cart"></i></a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>`
```

The div with the class name ROW is the main div inside it I want to make a dynamic data to show products coming in the response of my API.

This is what I am trying to embed using jQuery

```
fetch('http://localhost:5007/apk/getAllApks' , {

                    method : 'GET',
                    headers : {
                    'Content-type' : 'application/json'
                }, 
            })
            .then((result) => result.json())
            .then((finalresult) => {
              
                $.each(finalresult.doc, function(k, v) {
                    $("#productStack").html("<div class='col-md-6 col-lg-4'>
                        "<div class='product-item discount'>"
                            "<div class='product-item-inner'>"
                               "<span class='discount'>-25%</span>"
                                "<a href='./products/product-details.html' class='link'>"
                                    "<figure class='img-box'>"
                                        "<img src='../assets/img/products/quantum.png' alt='Ore Quantum PWG927.650'>"
                                    "</figure>"
                                "</a>"
                                "<div class='details'>
                                    "<span class='cat'><i class='uil uil-tag-alt'></i> Quantum</span>"
                                    "<a href='./products/product-details.html' class='link'>"
                                        "<h5 class='title'>Ore Quantum PWG927.650</h5>"
                                    "</a>"
                                    "<div class='star'>"
                                        "<i class='fa-solid fa-star'></i>"
                                        "<i class='fa-solid fa-star'></i>"
                                        "<i class='fa-solid fa-star'></i>"
                                        "<i class='fa-solid fa-star'></i>"
                                        "<i class='fa-solid fa-star-half-stroke'></i>"
                                        "<h4><span class='old-prc'>169.00&euro;</span>135.20&euro;</h4>"
                                    "</div>"
                                    "<a href='./single-products.html' class='go-to-cart'><i class='uil uil-shopping-bag shopping-cart cart'></i></a>"
                                "</div>"
                            "</div>"
                        "</div>"
                    "</div>");
                });

            });
```

I tried copying the Div and paste it inside the loop so it could be made dynamically.

Answer (score -1):

You can use **Jquery** `.append()` function.

for more details please visit official page [here](https://api.jquery.com/append/)

> For eg: you can rewrite your code as below

```
$.each(finalresult.doc, function(k, v) {
  $("#productStack").append("<div class='col-md-6 col-lg-4'> your remaining code will be here...</div>');
});
```

Please try.

Comment: where do i have to put this ID in above div?